# How to wait for a UITableView animation to finish?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UITableView and I'm doing an insertrow animation on it, and sometimes I have the deleterows animations too.

But the problem is that sometimes the delete is called before the insert finishes.

Is there a way to know when the animation is over?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your insert and delete calls with the [tableview beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] methods. This will make the animations happen simultaneously.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates